# Issues with the Microsoft Edge browser when loading iframe on document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, microsoft-edge

**I have the following html file:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                console.dir('iframe start');
                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = '<iframe id="xy" src="<url>" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>';
                console.dir('iframe end');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I start this page in Edge, it works. It loads the URL (that I omitted) and everything else works fine.

However, when I press F12 to see the developer tools, especially the console output, I don't see the "iframe start" and "iframe end" in the console, and when I reload the page, it doesn't work anymore, the iframe doesn't load at all.

When I close the developer tools and then refresh, it works again.

It all works just fine in Firefox or Chrome.

Why would opening the developer tools make any difference?

Comment: jQuery 1.x is beyond end of life and no longer gets security updates. Stop using it. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: I can't just switch to another version on my own, but I will suggest it to my team. I switched to 3.3.1 for this example and it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with JQuery 3.3.1 and it is working fine with MS Edge.

Other thing I noticed that you are using **Console.Dir** to print simple text.

> **Console.Dir** Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical
>   listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of
>   child objects.
>
> In other words, console.dir is the way to see all the properties of a
>   specified JavaScript object in console by which the developer can
>   easily get the properties of the object.

Reference:

[Console.dir()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir)

I try to replace the **console.dir** with **Console.log** which solves the issue.

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv">
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                console.log('iframe start');
                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = '<iframe id="xy" src="demo.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>';
                console.log('iframe end');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge:

[image]